# How to pass object/template as parameter in Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, parameter-passing, object-initialization

I'm attempting my first forray into jQuery. I'm trying to acheive the following, though I'm not sure of the terminology so will try to explain with an example using a kind of C#/pseudocode syntax.

Say I want an (anonymous) object as parameter, looking something like:

```
elemParameter {
    elemId,
    arg1,
    optionalArg2
}
```

and I want to pass an array/collection of these objects into my function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.myFunction(
        new { Id = "div1", Color = "blue", Animal = "dog" },
        new { Id = "div3", Color = "green" },
        new { Id = "div4", Color = "orange", Animal = "horse" }
    );
}
```

and then in my function, I need to access each object of the collection, something like:

```
(function($) {
    $.myFunction(var elemParams) {
        foreach (param in elemParams) {
            $('#' + param.Id).onclick = function() {
                this.css('background-color', param.Color);
                alert(param.Animal ?? 'no animal specified');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone give me a few pointers to the correct syntax for passing parameters this way? Or suggest a better way of acheiving the same if this isn't the correct way to go about things in javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is just a bit off, it would look something like this:

```
$(function() {
  function myFunction() {
    $.each(arguments, function(i, arg) {
      $('#' + arg.Id).click(function() {
        $(this).css('background-color', arg.Color);
        alert(arg.Animal || 'no animal specified');
      });
    });
  }
  myFunction({ Id: "div1", Color: "blue", Animal: "dog" },
             { Id: "div3", Color: "green" },
             { Id: "div4", Color: "orange", Animal: "horse" });​
});
```

[You can try a demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/uZrBN/), the syntax style is called [JavaScript object literal notation](http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/obj_lit.php), that's what you're googling for when looking for more info around this :)

Alternatively you can pass the objects in as an array if you want *other* arguments in addition to these, rather than using [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/core_javascript_1.5_reference/functions_and_function_scope/arguments) directly.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for "object literal notation." It looks like this:

```
{
    propertyName: propertyValue,
    propertyName2: propertyValue2
}
```

You don't use the `new` keyword with them, they're just a literal construct like strings ("foo") or numbers (42). Similarly, you have array literals:

```
["one", "two", "three"]
```

Here's your example updated:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.myFunction(
        // <== Start an array literal with [
        [
            // <== Colons rather than equal signs
            { Id: "div1", Color: "blue", Animal: "dog" },
            { Id: "div3", Color: "green" },
            { Id: "div4", Color: "orange", Animal: "horse" }
        // End the array literal with ]
        ]
    );
}
```

Note that it's important not to have a trailing comma in either an object or array literal, e.g.

```
["one", "two", "three", ]
                      ^--- Don't do that
{foo: "bar", x: 27, }
                  ^------- Or that
```

The question of whether they were valid was unclear (it's clear now as of the recent 5th edition) and IE (at least) chokes on them.

---

Off-topic, but typically property names in JavaScript code are in camelCase and start with a lower case letter (so, for instance, `animal` rather than `Animal`). This is purely style, however.